# how to set variable folder in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying set variable folder through shell script.

variable folder = /applog/yesr/month/day/ for example(/applog/2016/12/15). I am not able to set path.

DIR="/applog/*/*/*". I tried but it is not working through script.

Comment: There shouldn't be spaces between `var="/applog/2016/12/15"`

Comment: `DIR="/applog///*"` is right if you have a folder named `/applog/*`... Or you expect the asterisk to be expanded to an existing folder name such as `/applog/2015`?

Comment: "*I am not able to set path.*"   Please, when you post a problem here show **exactly** what you tried and show the whole error message.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`dir=/applog/2016/12/15`

`echo $dir` to verify

If you need to get all the folders inside, you can use find.

```
find /applog -type d
```

Or using `ls`:

```
ls -d /applog/*/
```

Comment: echo $DIR, not "dir". Linux is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find`.

Something like `find /applog -type d` is going to enumerate all folders inside "/applog" root folder.